# Can Q perform "contortionist" moves while masquerading in a humanoid body?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

In the novel *Q-in-Law*, by Peter David, there's a scene in which Lwaxana Troi approaches Q in the passageway. When Q boasts of his power, Lwaxana asks if Q is capable of bending backwards so that his head touches his lower back. When Lwaxana shows surprise when Q fails (or refuses to try), Q states, "I'm a god, not a contortionist!"

Now, I realize that the novels are not canon, but this part of the book always bugged me. I don't see why Q couldn't perform the trick that Lwaxana asked of him. If human contortionists could do it, then why couldn't Q, who didn't even have any bones, muscles, or the like?

Is there any additional information on this?

Answer (score 6):

It's not that he isn't capable of it, it's that he isn't capable of it in his present (human) form and he's promised Picard that he'll keep his powers in check, at least for the time being. This apparently includes overt demonstrations of his god-like abilities:

> **"No more of it," said Picard. "Understood, Q?" "Of course,"**

and

> "The bottom line is, **Q has promised to behave with restraint**. And your
>   mother is free to do as she pleases, within reason."

and

> "Can you bend your knees backwards? You know. Like that Earth bird
>   called a flamingo." **Q flexed his legs and found that they bent only
>   forward. "Not in this body, no. I'd have to change form."** "So you
>   can't do any-thing." He sighed. "I can do anything except bend my
>   knees backwards like a flamingo in this form." "Can you bend your
>   entire body backwards?" She gave a partial demonstration. "So that
>   your head touches the backs of your feet?" Q stared at her. "Why would
>   I want to do that?" "You said you could do anything." "I'm a god, not
>   a contortionist!" said Q in exasperation.

Comment: I don't see how Q bending his knees or touching his head against his feet would be "behaving without restraint." So, Richard, what you're saying is that Q was perfectly capable of doing what Lwaxana asked, but only by exercising his powers. Though it seems to me that the text indicates that Q's humanoid form is what limited Q, not Picard's order.

Comment: Q has agreed (albeit tacitly) not to use his powers which means he's essentially limited to his present human form. Without those powers, he can't do the things she says. If he used his powers, he could do them easily.

Comment: Q did not keep his promise perfectly, since in the same conversation he causes a piece of fruit to appear and disappear.

Comment: @t-1000 - And she seems less than impressed. A more effective use of power would definitely 'wow' her, but at the cost of breaking his word to Picard.